# Child selection in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In an `ExpandableListView` is it possible to initially select a child item so that the containing group is expanded and the list is scrolled to this child's position ?

I thought `setSelectedChild` would do the trick but it doesn't give any result.

I tested with the following piece of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TITLE = "title";

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ExpandableListView listView = new ExpandableListView(this);
    SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(this, 
        new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>() {
            {
                this.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                        this.put(TITLE, "Group 1");
                    }
                });
                this.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                        this.put(TITLE, "Group 2");
                    }
                });
                this.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                        this.put(TITLE, "Group 3");
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 
        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, 
        new String[] { TITLE }, 
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 
        new ArrayList<List<? extends Map<String,String>>>() {
            {
                this.add(new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>() {
                    {
                        this.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                            {
                                this.put(TITLE, "Child 1-1");
                            }
                        });
                        this.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                            {
                                this.put(TITLE, "Child 1-2");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                this.add(new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>() {
                    {
                        this.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                            {
                                this.put(TITLE, "Child 2-1");
                            }
                        });
                        this.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                            {
                                this.put(TITLE, "Child 2-2");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                this.add(new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>() {
                    {
                        this.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                            {
                                this.put(TITLE, "Child 3-1");
                            }
                        });
                        this.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                            {
                                this.put(TITLE, "Child 3-2");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
        new String[] { TITLE },
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }
    );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    setContentView(listView);

    listView.setSelectedChild(1, 1, true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a call to `listView.expandGroup()` before `setSelectedChild()`.

The `shouldExpandGroup` parameter set to true in `setSelectedChild()` seems only to work if there's at least one group expanded in the first place.

Comment: Why the document is not telling about `The shouldExpandGroup parameter set to true in setSelectedChild() seems only to work if there's at least one group expanded in the first place.`??

Comment: For me, it just expands, but not actually selecting. :(

Answer (score 0):

In an ExpandableListView is it possible to initially select a child item so that the containing group is expanded and the list is scrolled to this child's position:

```
//select child and open it's group
ExpListView.setSelectedChild(groupPos, childPos, true);
//scroll to selected child
ExpListView.smoothScrollToPosition(ExpListView.getFlatListPosition(ExpListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPos, childPos)));
```