# How in ExpandableListView first child item for all groups always checked when group open

Tags: android

when i click child item background changed successfully,but i cant change first child background (default) when group expand

```
list.setSelectedChild(groupposition,childposition,0);
```

here child position should be 0 when group expand.

Comment: I think @laalto's answer at [Child selection in ExpandableListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542892/child-selection-in-expandablelistview) can help you.

Comment: ya tried that,but in my scenario all groups are closed in initial state,once click group row  it will expand ,that time i want to highlight  the first position of child default